# what is the difference between [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)] and m=[[0]*n]*n

Tags: python

```
n=7
m=[[0]*n]*n
for i in range(n):
  m[i][i]=1
print(m)
```

Output:[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]

**BUT**

```
n=7
m = [[0 for x in range(n)] for x in range(n)] 
for i in range(n):
  m[i][i]=1
print(m)
```

Output:[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

why are the output different?

Comment: In the first case all the sub lists are the same object. In the second case they are different objects with the same (initial) value.

Comment: Look at `set(id(x) for x in m)` and you will see the difference clearly.

Comment: In the first case, try `m[0][i]=1` instead of `m[i][i]=1`. The result is the same because all the `m[i]` are the same object.